# Using AM greater than HM instead of AM greater than GM while problem solving

Tags: sequences-and-series, maxima-minima, means

While finding maxima or minima of some special functions, we use the idea of the arithmetic mean being greater than the geometric mean. This makes simplification easier and we can find maxima or minima of a certain function easily (compared to differentiating it).

But we know that the geometric mean is greater than the harmonic mean, does it mean that, if I use the inequality(GM>HM OR HM<AM) in certain functions, will i get a higher maxima or lower minima? If not, why?

***Clarification*** -We can find maxima or minima of certain *special* function using the result AM>GM. But we know that AM>GM>HM so will i get better bounds if i use AM>HM rather than AM>GM. Please give a generalized answer not for a specific examples.

Comment: Please give an example of how you're using AP>GP to get maxima/minima.

Comment: @Chrystomath To find the minima of  x+(1/x) for {x>0} ,Take the AM and GM of x,1/x so (x+1/x)/2>(x*1/x)^0.5 and simplify u will get x+1/x>2

Comment: In that example, the $HM<GM$ gives the same result as $GM<AM$. This is hardly surprising given that for two terms $AM.HM=GM^2$, so $AM/GM = GM/HM$.

Comment: @Chrystomath yes even i noticed that.But the relation AM/GM=GM/HM is not true for all cases.

Comment: So what is your specific question? It's not clear what you mean by "if I use the inequality...". Is it whether $AM>HM$ should be better than $AM>GM$?

Comment: @Chrystomath I edited the question .I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is vague as it refers to "certain functions".

If what is meant by the question is that the inequality $AM>HM$ should give a better estimate than $AM>GM$ (since $GM>HM$), then the answer is normally not.

In general $$AM\ge GM,\qquad AM\ge HM = \frac{HM}{GM}GM$$ Since $HM/GM\le1$, one can see that the second inequality is less sharp than the first, in the sense that the first one implies the second. So anything that comes out of the second inequality can also be shown using the first.

But there are many cases, where the two are equivalent. For example, take $F=a+b$, then $AM(a,b)=F/2$, $GM(a,b)=\sqrt{ab}$, $HM(a,b)=2ab/F$.

Hence $GM\le AM$ gives $F\ge2\sqrt{ab}$.

$HM\le AM$ gives $F/2\ge2ab/F$, which is the same inequality $F\ge2\sqrt{ab}$.

Comment: So in your case $f(x)=2*AM$. $AM > GM$ is a stronger inequality than $AM > HM$ (because $max(GM,HM)=GM$) . So it is expected from the beginning that $AM > GM$ will produce a better bound no ?

Comment: If I am not getting too much confused, does this mean than any time we have a proof where $AM > HM$ is used, we can at least try to produce tighter bounds using $AM > GM$ ?

Comment: If we already something lower bounded by GM, why should you want to lower bound by HM, which is a lower value than GM ? You would get to a worse estimate, as the answer of Crhystomath nicely shows... I am getting confused...